# R: Calling table() on multiple variables

Tags: r

I have to call the `table()` function on 10 variables in R. Is there any way of doing it in one shot, without calling them individually like `table(v1)`, `table(v2)`... `table(v10)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your variables are arranged as columns in a data.frame, you could use `lapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(aa = rpois(10, 4), bb = rpois(10, 3), c = rpois(10, 7))

tabList <- lapply(df, table)
```

Then you get a list with the various tables:

```
> tabList
$aa

1 3 4 5 6 7 
2 3 2 1 1 1 

$bb

1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 4 1 2 

$c

 3  4  5  6  7  9 11 12 
 1  1  1  3  1  1  1  1
```

**EDIT:**

For variables across multiple data.frames, you might try putting them into a list and then using `lapply` again:

```
df2 <- df[sample(rownames(df), 15, replace = TRUE), ]

df3 <- df[sample(rownames(df), 20, replace = TRUE), ]

dfList <- list(df = df, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)

lapply(dfList, function(x) lapply(x, FUN = table))
```

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks. Is there anything similar when the variables are not from the same dataframe?

Comment: @user702432, That should be possible, too. Please see my suggestion below **EDIT**