# Histogram of two or more binary variables in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have two binary vectors, let's say:

```
male  female unknown
0     1      0
0     1      0
1     0      0
0     0      1
1     0      0
```

and I want a histogram of this data. Similarly I want histograms for other vectors where there might be more vectors like this. It is safe to assume that all vectors have the same length, they come from the same data frame.

I have an idea how to do this by counting or summing over each vector but what would be a nice way or the right way to do this?

Tnx.

Comment: can you break out the microsoft paint and hand-draw the histogram you're looking for in this example?  are you sure you don't want a barplot?  :)

Comment: hmm tnx.. you gave me a good idea with the barplots.. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071083/r-calling-table-on-multiple-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some strange data to be looking at presenting with a histogram, but never mind. I'd use `ggplot2`. If you melt the data (using `reshape2`) then the number of vectors or their length is irrelevant.

```
df <- data.frame(male=c(0,0,1,0,1),
                 female=c(1,1,0,0,0),
                 unknown=c(0,0,0,1,0))

df.m <- melt(df)
str(df.m)
hist(df.m$value ~ df.m$variable)
ggplot(df.m, aes(value)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill=variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) #This depends on how you want your different variables split up.
```

[image]
    #If you want them on the same plot, then:

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(value)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill=variable), position="dodge")
```

Comment: ok tnx, you gave me my answer and a bit more, I realize I was asking the wrong question. the melt function is something I want to use (including only 1's) and then do a bar plot

Comment: So get the sum of each variable?

Comment: well that's what I first did and thought it was just quick and dirty, but looks like it's a good solution after all.
tnx for the help

Comment: @alexwhan How can I see the 1's more spread out like a histogram? I have 30 variables and they're all scrunched up in the center of the chart.